# Multiple questions regarding not working internet connection

Tags: support, questions, exact-duplicates

I am not quite sure how the moderators can do that, but lots of users (including me) had problems with internet connection

[There is existing solution on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet) but I honestly do not know if it is possible to promote that solution here or how to flag all the questions as duplicate

I offer my help in purging these questions to one, but I need to know how to proceed next

Comment: They should all be marked duplicate of [this question](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4183/how-can-i-fix-networking-wi-fi-and-ethernet-not-being-available-after-update) answered by Lewis Goddard.